# PHP cURL fetch video by url on local server

Tags: curl, iframe, video-streaming, php-curl, laravel-middleware

Here's what I have for **example**:

1. **ServerA** : *http://192.168.12.12/cctv/monitor1* (This shows a CCTV video stream of monitor 1)
2. **ServerB** : *http://192.168.13.13/monitoring* (This is my webpage which i want to show the video stream from **ServerA**) *ps : this also can ping/access to **ServerA**
3. PC1 : PC that have permission ping/access to both **ServerA** and **ServerB**
4. PC2 : PC that have ***NO PERMISSION***  to ping/access to ServerA, but can access to **ServerB** (My web)

///////

It works fine if I just show the streaming from client-side cuz **PC1** got full permission to access **ServerA**.

But theres the problem when it come to use PC2 to access my webpage, it wont show the video of **ServerA**.

I've tried to use cURL and it ended up a super long loading (more like infinite load), still i don't know if it was possible to fetch a video from cURL or not.

The **GOAL** im trying to reach is to make my web as a middleware for ServerA and PC2

PC2 > my web (ServerB) > the videos (ServerA)

///---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Here's my explanation of my codes for example :**

/* Loop url of the stream videos*/

`for($i=0;$i<count($cctv);$i++){`

`echo "<iframe src='".$cctv['link']."'/>"`

`}`

/* Function of cURL (honestly i use this function for each of the cctv link i've looped like **checkcURL($cctv['link'])**  ) */

`$ch = curl_init($url);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,0);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

`$response = curl_exec($ch);`

`curl_close($ch);`

`echo $response;`

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sorry if both of my explanation either my english was bad, hope you guys have a good day

Answer (score 1):

just want to add, don't forget to always put maximum timeout (i.e. 60s, can be vary according to your usecase) on your any production grade projects when doing curl or http request. That way, your services are not by any means dependent or at other's services mercy. Even if the remotes / external services hung up, your services won't.

Have a nice day :)